# Flash datagrid text and masking problem?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, text, datagrid

I am using AS3, I have a problem in displaying the datagrid. The Datagrid text not showing behind mask. If i put outside the mask, then the data(text) will appear. How do I display the datagridc text/data inside the mask layer?

Comment: more details about what you're trying to do please. Are you using the mask property or just a container to act like the mask?

Answer (score 0):

System fonts don't display in a mask.
You need to embed your font.
The simplest way to do this is via a css file.
The first example below shows how to embed a trueType font.
The second example shows how you can embed a non-trueType font into Flash, then reference the resulting swf file.

```
@font-face {
   src: url(../fonts/MyriadWebPro.ttf);
   fontFamily: myriadPro;
}

@font-face {
   src:url("../fonts/embededFonts.swf");
   fontFamily: "Myriad Pro";
   fontWeight: bold;
}
```